# Model isn't updating when selected option changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

My Angular.js project features a select element bound to a model. On load the appropriate option is selected however selecting another option doesn't seem to update the model, at least not permanently. If I change the model programmatically however the results are as expected.

The controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.month = "08"; // this default value is selected on-load as expected
  $scope.updateMonth = function() {
   console.log($scope.month); // this shows the original value not the newly selected value
   // a http request and other things happen here...
  };
  $scope.logMonth = function(month) {
   console.log(month); // this shows the newly selected value as expected
  }
 });
```

The template:

```
<select ng-model="month" ng-change="logMonth(month);">
 <option value="07">07</option>
 <option value="08">08</option>
 <option value="09">09</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="updateMonth();">Update Month</button>
```

Comment: In your template, `logMonth(month);` is present and yet you don't have that argument in `$scope.logMonth`...what happens when you make that just `ng-change="logMonth()"`?

Comment: you get errors in console?

Comment: Just created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snt8z7do/) and I'm unable to duplicate your issue.

Comment: the extra `});` in the code is it from copy paste ?

Comment: ZackMacomber and Akis_Tfs apologies, looks like I missed some stuff when I redacted some code to make it easier for you all to read, I just updated it. Lex thanks for testing, that'd likely indicate it's an issue with the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an angular scoping problem. Scope inheritance applies to objects on scopes but not to primitives. Try changing `$scope.month = "08"` to `$scope.month = {selected: "08"}`. Then in your controller, change the html to the following.

`<select ng-model="month.selected" ng-change="logMonth(month.selected);">`

Comment: This did the trick. My text inputs and other form elements were using $rootScope and they behaved as expected so I assumed $scope would too. I'll have to do some more reading on the specifics because I'm relatively new to Angular.js. Thanks again!